# Kotlin Fuel Increase buffer size

Tags: kotlin, buffer, fuel

I'm using fuel to make some http requests for large blobs of JSON. In this particular case I know I'm always going to receive 100s of kilobytes of JSON and never anything smaller. I've noticed the buffersize on the input stream from responses is 8KiB, is there a way to adjust this? I wonder if I might get better performance with a larger buffer.